# What will happen if execution of a Make recipe does not change the target file?

Tags: makefile, recipe

We have a Makefile with a recipe that invokes a script to generate a C header that is then included into many other source files:

```
gen-header.h: $(INPUT)
    script.py $(INPUT) -o gen-header.h

# GMake and GCC rules to produce and include .d files for .c files 
# to track header/source dependencies follow
```

Recently, an *optimization* was added to script.py so that it avoids overwriting the output file if it exists and its contents would not change (e.g. if only non-functional comments in `$(INPUT)` have been updated). Neither access nor creation times of the output `gen-header.h` would be updated in such case.

The intended goal of the optimization is of course to avoid recompilation of all files depending on gen-header.h whenever changes in `$(INPUT)` are not propagating to the header (there are other generation passes which use different parts of `$(INPUT)` to produce different source files unrelated to gen-header.h)

The question is: would such situation confuse Make, or is it an acceptable behavior for a recipe?

Comment: I don't think the answers below are wrong per se.  But they do make it seem more ominous than it is.  This behavior you are using is actually well-defined and well-supported and the foundation to a LOT of build systems, including the basis for autotools build environments used by all GNU software: ever single makefile generated by automake will use this capability to avoid rebuilding code that doesn't need to be rebuilt when configuration changes are made.  You should feel free to use it and feel good about it with no worries or concerns.

Answer (score 0):

> The question is: would such situation confuse Make, or is it an acceptable behavior for a recipe?

Would it *confuse* `make`? No. `make` does not inherently fail if the recipe for a target does not build that target, or does not build it on every run.  It might or might not cause a problem for your build, depending on that and other details of your makefile, but the case you describe sounds benign.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't *confuse* make, as such, and would be harmless in this particular case, since the only result would be the action `script.py $(INPUT) -o gen-header.h` being re-run redundantly each time Make is run.

However, you'd want to avoid this in general.

A rule like

```
target: source
    action
```

is, in a sense, a ‘promise’ to Make that running the `action` will result in `target` being newer than `source`.  I would experience zero surprise to discover that there were circumstances (possibly involving side-effects of the action?) where this did cause a problem.

Fortunately, this is easy to avoid.  In this case I'd write

```
# Note: `script.py` doesn't rewrite `gen-header.h` if it wouldn't change
gen-header.h: $(INPUT)
    script.py $(INPUT) -o gen-header.h && touch $@
```

...if only to remind myself that this happens, when debugging the Makefile in future.  That forces the target file `$@` to be newer, and so keeps the implicit promise to Make.